# How to generate n-2 distinc float numbers with only 2 decimals and sorted ascending in in a given range

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
var = numpy.random.uniform(a, b, n - 2)
var.sort()
print(var)
```

This code prints `n - 2` float numbers, but I want numbers with only 2 decimals, like `2.54`. If I iterate the list var, and round it to two places (`round(var[i], 2)`), it is possible to have repeated numbers. eg.:

```
var[2] = 5.678342
var[6] = 5.67324222
```

After rounding both become `5.67`, which is not distinct.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best way, and it's hard to help you more without more context on your application. The idea is to turn the generated array into a set of unique elements, and while the set size is not `n-2`, generate a new element and add it to the set if it's not already present.

```
import numpy as np

a = 0
b = 5
n = 12

var = np.random.uniform(a, b, n-2)

var = set(np.round(var, 2))
while len(var) != n-2:
    # generate a new number
    number = np.round(np.random.uniform(a, b, 1)[0], 2)
    # add it if it is not already present
    if number not in var:
        var.update(number)
```

You can turn the set back into a numpy array or a list at the end and then sort it.

Comment: Context: knowing n, x_0, x_n (read from the keyboard), construct x_i so that x_i-1 <x_i, for any i in 0...n

x_i float numbers with 2 decimals

Comment: I think it is corect what you give me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want numbers that have a fixed number of decimals, you are actually asking for distinct integers, divided by the appropriate scale. In your case, the scale is 100.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

scale = 100
lower = int(round(scale * a))
range_ = int(round(scale * b)) - lower
var = (rng.choice(range_, replace=False, size=n - 2, shuffle=False) + lower) / scale
```

Generating integers in general does not avoid the problem of repeated elements. You need to ensure sampling without replacement to do that.

Comment: This is a way smarter solution!

Comment: @Mathieu. Thank you. I won't disagree :)